java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key enum - Kafka/Avro
What i'm doing wrong?
I have error when access Kafka topic with Avro schema
Error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key enum (attempted merging values 
com.provectus.kafka.ui.util.jsonschema.SimpleFieldSchema@11e16b91 
and com.provectus.kafka.ui.util.jsonschema.SimpleFieldSchema@22fb626a)  
at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:135) 
Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):   *__checkpoint ⇢ 
com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.CorsGlobalConfiguration$$Lambda$1007/0x00000008016952f0 [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint 
⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] 
*__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.ReadOnlyModeFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]    
*__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]  
*__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]   
*__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] 
*__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]   
*__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] 
*__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]   
*__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]    
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain] 
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] 
*__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/clusters/local-kafka/topic/sims.sim_events_v2/serdes?use=SERIALIZE" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]Original Stack Trace:       at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:135)     at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:182)       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)      at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)      at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)     at 
...


My schema:
{
    "namespace": "sims.sim_events_v2",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "SIMEvent",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "event_id",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}


Schema Subject:
sims.sim_events_v2-value

queue: sims.sim_events_v2
No erros in Topic -> Messages
Decoded Messages -> value in Topic

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How is this related to Avro or causing an issue with actually consuming the data?The error has nothing to do with Avro... Duplicate key enum... util.jsonschema.SimpleFieldSchema
